# warning with hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, accents

I have met warning:"Package hyperref Warning: Composite letter `\textdotbelow+u'" when i use this code to create a bookmark

```
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
```

I don't know the reason for this warning, how to avoid and fix the warning.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @egreg :Sorry, i don't understand the meaning of your question.

Comment: I can only conjecture that you're writing your document in Vietnamese. Please, add the first lines of your document, where you declare the language used (something like in my example code below).

Answer (score 11):

Pass the `unicode` option to `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\section{a}
\end{document}
```

Without the option I indeed get the warning

```
Package hyperref Warning: Composite letter `\textdotbelow+u'
(hyperref)                not defined in PD1 encoding,
(hyperref)                removing `\textdotbelow' on input line 5.
```

The warning disappears with that option. This should be independent of the input encoding chosen; I've tried with `viscii`, `tcvn`, `vps`, and `utf8x`

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\pdfbookmark{\texorpdfstring{Contents}{\contentsname}}{Contents}
```

For *Contents* In `\textorpdfstring` you can use any translation without special characters which are not possible in the bookmarks of a pdf file, like your u with a underdot