# Cannot display \textsuperscript and trademark symbol on subsection title

Tags: text, superscripts, subsection

**This is what I have:**, source: [How to typeset subscript in usual text mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-to-typeset-subscript-in-usual-text-mode).

```
\subsection{Code from Moral Kombat\texorpdfstring{\textsuperscript{\texttrademark}{Code from Moral Kombat\texttrademark}}}
```

**Packages:**

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{xcode}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pifont,mdframed}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath} % For using \text in equations
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Hyperlinks
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalise]{cleveref} % Better in-doc refs
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\input{hyperendnotes.sty}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[title,toc,titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} % Better figure and table placements
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{csquotes} % For blockquote
\usepackage[labelfont=it, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} % used to include pdf to appendicies
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{longtable}
% \usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
\usepackage{xpatch}
```

**Result:**

[image]

---

**EDIT: This works:**

```
\subsection{Code from Moral Kombat\textsuperscript{\texttrademark}}
```

***But, this results in the following WARNING(s).***

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\mathsurround' on input line 9.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\z@' on input line 9.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `superscript' on input line 9.
```

[image]

Comment: You misunderstood the linked answer. Maybe read my comment added there https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1013/how-to-typeset-subscript-in-usual-text-mode#comment1689447_1017 ?

Comment: Neither `\textsuperscript` nor `\texttrademark` is acceptable in a pdf string.  Perhaps a directly entered Unicode character would work (probably depends on which TeX engine you're using), or the brute force "(TM)".

Comment: Does the `\title` or `\author` use the offending code?

Comment: @rallg, I am using: `\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,11pt]{article}`

Comment: To expand on the comments above: _inside_ `\textorpdfstring` you add the two versions, this is a command with two arguments. So either `\subsection{\texorpdfstring{Code from Mortal Kombat\textsuperscript{\texttrademark}}{Code from Mortal Kombat (tm)}}` or `\subsection{Code from Mortal Kombat\texorpdfstring{\textsuperscript{\texttrademark}}{ (tm)}}`. Note that I replaced "Moral" by "Mortal" in the example, as I believe you are talking about the video game and not about the [documentary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencer_Halpin%27s_Moral_Kombat).

Comment: Note also that `\texttrademark` is already superscript by itself, so you could also just use that (although it does look a bit large when it is not superscripted a second time).

Comment: @Marijn, please post that as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Alix this is a duplicate, we have many questions where (correct use of) `\texorpdfstring` is the answer. I will see if I can find a suitable post later to use as a close target.

Comment: @Marijn -- I can't find a decent duplicate, but this answer might help you put together a good answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87751

Comment: The question I picked is not an exact duplicate (i.e., it doesn't contain the same mistake as in the question here of duplicating the text outside and inside of the command) but the answer does clearly explain how `\texorpdfstring` is supposed to be used, which should be sufficient to fix the mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the solution:**

```
\subsection{Code from Mortal Kombat\texorpdfstring{\textsuperscript{\texttrademark}}{ (TM)}}
```